# Spring: BasicHttp doesn't work with jdbcAuthentication when hitting requests from Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, postman

I am trying to implement `jdbcAuthentication` in my project. The problem is that it works when I make requests from `browser` but when I make requests from `Postman` it doesn't work, I mean authentication doesn't happen and even random credentials work.

However if I use `inMemoryAuthentication` it works fine for both browser and Postman. This is my code inside `SecurityConfig`.

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");    

   // This works -->    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

In postman I make a `POST` request.

In `Authorization` type I select basic auth and enter the credentials which are then populated in the Authorization header below

These are the headers

```
Content-Type:application/json
X-XSRF-TOKEN:{{X-CSRF-TOKEN}}
Authorization:Basic ajhsjajywshhshshsssss
```

If I comment the `jdbcAUthentication` part and uncomment the `inMomeryAuthentication` code, authentication works from both broswer and postman. Can someone please help me, why is this happening? Am I missing something? Thanks !!

Comment: Please mention request specs (type, content, etc) when using postman.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.authenticated()`, this means the user is already authenticated and you want to allow users that are already authenticated (aka "remembered").

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
    .authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
```

But actually, what you want to do is to authenticate for first time, so for this you need to change it to `fullyAuthenticated`

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable();
```

If you check the **[AuthorizedUrl](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html)** documentation you will find:

> **authenticated()**: Specify that URLs are allowed by any authenticated user.
>
> **fullyAuthenticated()**:
> Specify that URLs are allowed by users who have authenticated and were not "remembered".